# Parse Large amount of Json in Excel

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have an application which reads in files containing json data parses them then performs some formatting and calculations.

The Core of the code itself works fine, however the issue I have is that it is slow.

I got Json Parsing code from another site (not sure if i'm allowed to link to it), and what I do is I split the file from the data into an array, Parse each row and put it into another array then perform all my tasks later.

The slow part is the Parsing of the data, overall it's pretty quick and works through about 10-15 rows a second, however my files have upwards of 5k rows of data in them, meaning each file takes roughly 5 minutes, and when as there are hundreds of files to get through, it takes almost an entire day to full parse all the data.

I've attached snippets of my code (not the full parsing functions as that's really long) just to give an idea of how my code is currently working

My query is, is there a way I can parse the entire file (each record is seperated by a line feed) instead of having to parse it row by row?

```
sourceArray = Split(sourceText, vbLf)
For Ctr = LBound(sourceArray) To UBound(sourceArray)
    Set dic = ParseJSON(sourceArray(Ctr)
    For Each v In dic
        (do some formatting stuff, I tested by completely commenting out this part to make sure the ParseJSON is where the slowdown is)
    next v
Next Ctr
```

Json Parser code

```
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
' VBA JSON Parser
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Function ParseJSON(json$, Optional key$ = "obj") As Object
  p = 1
  token = Tokenize(json)
  Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  If token(p) = "{" Then ParseObj key Else ParseArr key
  Set ParseJSON = dic
End Function

Function ParseObj(key$)
  Do: p = p + 1
    Select Case token(p)
        Case "]"
        Case "[":  ParseArr key
        Case "{"
                   If token(p + 1) = "}" Then
                       p = p + 1
                       dic.Add key, "null"
                   Else
                       ParseObj key
                   End If
            
        Case "}":  key = ReducePath(key): Exit Do
        Case ":":  key = key & "." & token(p - 1)
        Case ",":  key = ReducePath(key)
        Case Else: If token(p + 1) <> ":" Then dic.Add key, token(p)
    End Select
  Loop
End Function

Function ParseArr(key$)
Dim e&

    Do: p = p + 1
        Select Case token(p)
            Case "}"
            Case "{":  ParseObj key & ArrayID(e)
            Case "[":  ParseArr key
            Case "],":  e = e
            Case "]":  Exit Do
            
            Case ":":  key = key & ArrayID(e)
            Case ",":  e = e + 1
            Case Else: dic.Add key & ArrayID(e), token(p)
        End Select
    Loop
End Function

'-------------------------------------------------------------------
' Support Functions
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Tokenize(s$)
  Const Pattern = """(([^""\\]|\\.)*)""|[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?|\w+|[^\s""']+?"
  Tokenize = RExtract(s, Pattern, True)
End Function

Function RExtract(s$, Pattern, Optional bGroup1Bias As Boolean, Optional bGlobal As Boolean = True)

  Dim c&, m, n, v
  With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = bGlobal
    .MultiLine = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = Pattern
    If .test(s) Then
      Set m = .Execute(s)
      ReDim v(1 To m.Count)
      For Each n In m
        c = c + 1
        v(c) = n.Value
        If bGroup1Bias Then If Len(n.subMatches(0)) Or n.Value = """""" Then v(c) = n.subMatches(0)
      Next
    End If
  End With
  RExtract = v
End Function

Function ArrayID$(e)
  ArrayID = "(" & e & ")"
End Function

Function ReducePath$(key$)
  If InStr(key, ".") Then ReducePath = Left(key, InStrRev(key, ".") - 1) Else ReducePath = key
End Function

Function ListPaths(dic)
  Dim s$, v
  For Each v In dic
    s = s & v & " --> " & dic(v) & vbLf
  Next
End Function

Function GetFilteredValues(dic, Match)
  Dim c&, i&, v, w
  v = dic.Keys
  ReDim w(1 To dic.Count)
  For i = 0 To UBound(v)
    If v(i) Like Match Then
        c = c + 1
        w(c) = dic(v(i))
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve w(1 To c)
  GetFilteredValues = w
End Function

Function GetFilteredTable(dic, cols)
  Dim c&, i&, j&, v, w, z
  v = dic.Keys
  z = GetFilteredValues(dic, cols(0))
  ReDim w(1 To UBound(z), 1 To UBound(cols) + 1)
  For j = 1 To UBound(cols) + 1
     z = GetFilteredValues(dic, cols(j - 1))
     For i = 1 To UBound(z)
        w(i, j) = z(i)
     Next
  Next
  GetFilteredTable = w
End Function

Function OpenTextFile$(f)
  With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile f
    OpenTextFile = .ReadText
  End With
End Function
```

Sample Data

{
"op": "mcm",
"clk": "4985835795",
"pt": 1641446989915,
"mc": [
{
"id": "1.193068822",
"rc": [
{
"batl": [
[
0,
85,
10
]
],
"ltp": 0.0,
"tv": 0.0,
"id": 536162
},
{
"batl": [
[
0,
85,
5
]
],
"ltp": 0.0,
"tv": 0.0,
"id": 36024159
},
{
"batb": [
[
0,
1.02,
322
]
],
"ltp": 0.0,
"tv": 0.0,
"id": 22734575
},
{
"batb": [
[
0,
1.02,
322
]
],
"ltp": 0.0,
"tv": 0.0,
"id": 16286497
},
{
"batb": [
[
0,
1.02,
322
]
],
"ltp": 0.0,
"tv": 0.0,
"id": 18673417
},
{
"batl": [
[
0,
85,
10
]
],
"ltp": 0.0,
"tv": 0.0,
"id": 38835846
},
{
"batl": [
[
0,
85,
10
]
],
"ltp": 0.0,
"tv": 0.0,
"id": 1527689
},
{
"batb": [
[
0,
1.02,
322
]
],
"ltp": 0.0,
"tv": 0.0,
"id": 36394575
},
{
"batb": [
[
0,
1.02,
322
]
],
"ltp": 0.0,
"tv": 0.0,
"id": 1276636
}
]
}
]
}

Comment: Can you add a reference to the JSON Parser? Also, provide an example of what the file structure looks like?

Comment: "I got Json Parsing code from stackoverflow" means nothing. Do you use the 'jsonConveter` from [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)? If not, try it, or at least show  it here if you love such a solution. The one I suggest to be used parses the whole string a once. If you use it, it already returns an object keeping dictionaries and you can process any keys/items of it as you wan/need.

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake, The parser is not from stackoverflow, it's from a different site. Am I allowed to  link it here? I'll copy and paste all the code into my question.

I didn't include it originally as that part of the code isn't the issue

Comment: I've also added an example of a single json row of data (my files have several thousand rows like this)

Comment: Ok, so each line is a JSON object. What are you doing with all this data once it is parsed? Your sample has 742 characters, and you have over 5,000 lines of the same thing? This is almost 4 million characters to Parse through, so I would imagine with a VBA implementation it would take some time.

Comment: I'm pulling out the relevant data from each object and putting it into an array to be processed later (that part is fairly quick)

and yes, that is the problem I have, i parse each row 1 at a time, hence my query on if it is possible to parse an entire file (basically parse the json once, instead of 5000 times for a single file)

I thought about merging all the lines together into one giant json, but had issue with the duplicate keys in the dictionary

Comment: I don't believe parsing it all at once would improve performance, it is still doing the same computation. If you really wanted to though, you could edit the file, where you surround the entire file with array brackets `[]` and add a comma at the end each row minus the last row. Then you could parse it in one go, but again I think it will take roughly the same amount of time.

Comment: i'll give it a go and see if that is any faster

Comment: Forget about the formatting of  the JSON file itself. As long as the JSON data is valid and well-formed, then any parser used should focus on matching the enclosed data (`{}` or `[]`) regardless of how many lines it crosses. Someone could come in and "helpfully" reformat your file and then your parser would stop working. I do recommend the parser linked by @FaneDuru. It's very fast and will give you access to your data as an array to iterate.

Comment: @MichaelLiew not only are you _allowed_ to link to the source of your code, you are _required_ to, in order to give proper attribution

Comment: If the parser itself should be fast enough, even for the whole string, I think it would be good to show us what really exists behind "`(do some formatting stuff, I tested by completely commenting out this part to make sure the ParseJSON is where the slowdown is)`". Maybe you did not choose the most efficient way of processing there...

Comment: Thanks for all the comments everyone, Been very helpful

For those that wanted it, the site I got my Parser code from was 
https://medium.com/swlh/excel-vba-parse-json-easily-c2213f4d8e7a

I've tried Roberts suggestion of adding [] around my entire file data prior to feeding it into the parser code (instead of lots of individual rows) and it is much much faster!

to the level of 10 seconds vs 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this library to parse a json file with 4560 objects and 532kb under 3 seconds.

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

```
Sub main()

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim JsonTS As TextStream
    Dim JsonText As String
    Dim Parsed As Dictionary
    
    Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("sample4.json", ForReading)
    JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
    JsonTS.Close
    
    Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)
    
    For i = 1 To Parsed("people").Count
      With Sheets(1)
        Range("A" & i).Value = Parsed("people")(i)("firstName")
        Range("B" & i).Value = Parsed("people")(i)("lastName")
        Range("C" & i).Value = Parsed("people")(i)("gender")
        Range("D" & i).Value = Parsed("people")(i)("age")
        Range("E" & i).Value = Parsed("people")(i)("number")
      End With
    Next

End Sub
```

> {
> "people": [
> {
> "firstName": "Joe",
> "lastName": "Jackson",
> "gender": "male",
> "age": 28,
> "number": "7349282382"
> }
> ]
> }